# Get Video Source from variable

Tags: development, jquery, csom, iframe, video

I am currently using SharePoint to query a pages library for a video, the aim is to then display this video in an iframe, I am currently using csom to get the video source from a Page, however this returns the code below:

```
<dl>
  <dt>MediaSource</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="/Videos/Life Changing/video1.mp4">link</a>
  </dd>
  <dt>PreviewImageSource</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="/Videos/Life Changing/Preview Images/snapshot.png">link</a>
  </dd>

  <dd>Inline</dd>
  <dt>AutoPlay</dt>
  <dd>False</dd>
  <dt>Loop</dt>
  <dd>False</dd>
  <dt>InlineHeight</dt>
  <dd>360px</dd>
  <dt>InlineWidth</dt>
  <dd>640px</dd>
  <dt>ShowEmbedControl</dt>
  <dd>True</dd>
  <dt>ConfigureFromContext</dt>
  <dd>False</dd>
  <dt>VideoSetSource</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="/Videos/Life Changing">link</a>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I need to extract the ".mp4" url and also the ".png" url so that I can use them in the iframe, how would be best to go about this please?

My code in full is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getVideoNews);
})


function getVideoNews() {
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope=\'Recursive\'><RowLimit>5</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Comments\' /><FieldRef Name=\'LikesCount\' /><FieldRef Name=\'FileRef\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Rich_x0020_Video_x0020_Embed\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Summary_x0020_Text\' /></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ContentType\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>News Video</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'True\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('News Videos');
    collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(list);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, newsvideoSuccessHandler),
     Function.createDelegate(this, newsvideoErrorHandler));
}

function newsvideoSuccessHandler(result) {

    listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var newsvideotitle = oListItem.get_item("Title");
        var newsvideolink = oListItem.get_item("FileRef");
        var newsvideo = oListItem.get_item("Rich_x0020_Video_x0020_Embed");

    }

}

function newsvideoErrorHandler(sender, args) {
    alert('Camelot News Video Error: \nRequest failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i use to get videos info from a "Asset Library", maybe this can help you. I don't know how to get the preview pic but should be right there:

```
getDataFormVideosList:function(next){
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>' +
                            '<ViewFields>' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\' />' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'Title\' />' +
                            '</ViewFields>' +
                        '</View>');
    executeAsyncCamlQuery('your list name', camlQuery, null, function (err, items) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        var lListItemsInfo = [];
        var lListItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (lListItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var lListItem = lListItemEnumerator.get_current();
            lListItemsInfo.push({
                id: lListItem.get_item('ID'),
                title: lListItem.get_item('Title')
            });
        }
        return next(null, lListItemsInfo);
    });
},
getVideo:function(next){
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>' +
                            '<Query>' +
                                '<Where>' +
                                    '<Eq>' +
                                        '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\' />' +
                                        '<Value Type=\'Number\' >{YourIdGoesHere}</Value>' +
                                    '</Eq> ' +
                                '</Where>' +
                            '</Query> ' +
                            '<ViewFields>' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\' />' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'Title\' />' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'VideoSetDescription\' />' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'EncodedAbsUrl\' />' +
                                '<FieldRef Name=\'FileRef\' />' +
                            '</ViewFields>' +
                        '</View>');

    var include = "Include(ID, Title, FileRef, EncodedAbsUrl, VideoSetDescription, FileSystemObjectType)";
    executeAsyncCamlQuery('your list name', camlQuery, include, function (err, items) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        var lListItemsInfo = {};
        var lListItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        lListItemEnumerator.moveNext();
        var lListItem = lListItemEnumerator.get_current();

        if(lListItem.get_fileSystemObjectType() == "1") {
            executeAsyncGetFiles(lListItem.get_item('FileRef'), null, function(err, files) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                var lFilesEnumerator = files.getEnumerator();
                lFilesEnumerator.moveNext();
                var lFile = lFilesEnumerator.get_current();

                //THIS IS THE OBJECT WITH YOUR VIDEO INFO***********
                lListItemsInfo = {
                    id: lListItem.get_item('ID'),
                    title: lListItem.get_item('Title'),
                    descripcion: lListItem.get_item('VideoSetDescription'),
                    url: lFile.get_serverRelativeUrl(),
                    extension: getFileExtension(lFile.get_serverRelativeUrl()),
                    folderUrl: lListItem.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl')
                };
                //***************************************************
                return next(null, lListItemsInfo);
            });
        }
    });
},
executeAsyncGetFiles: function (folderServerRelativeUrl, include, next) {
    try{
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var lWebSite = context.get_web();
        var lFolder = lWebSite.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativeUrl);
        var lFiles = lFolder.get_files();

        if (include)
            context.load(lFiles, include);
        else 
            context.load(lFiles);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            if (next && typeof (next) == "function") next(null, lFiles);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            var lError = new Error('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            if (next && typeof (next) == "function") next(lError);
            else throw (lError);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

},
executeAsyncCamlQuery: function (listName, camlQuery, include, next) {
    try {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var lWebSite = context.get_web();
        var lList = lWebSite.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var lItems = lList.getItems(camlQuery);

        if (include)
            context.load(lItems, include);
        else 
            context.load(lItems);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            if (next && typeof (next) == "function") next(null, lItems);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            var lError = new Error('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            if (next && typeof (next) == "function") next(lError);
            else throw (lError);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
},
getFileExtension: function(fileName) {
    return fileName.substr((~-fileName.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2);
}
```